# i want find if an element occurs consecutively a certain no. of times in a list H occurs k times consecutively in n experiments

Tags: python, list, numpy, data-science

a coin is tossed n times and if during those n times heads occurs consecutively k times then one had to pay a dollar , the problem is in last result e[n] in the list and it cant work as e[n+1] doesnt exist
code

```
def coinflip2(n,k):
ϵ=[]
h=1
c=0
for i in range(n):
    e= np.random.uniform(0,1)
    if(e>0.5):
        e=1
    else:
        e=0
    ϵ.append(e)
print(ϵ)    
for i in range (len(ϵ)):
    if(ϵ[i]==ϵ[i+1]):
        c=c+1
    else:
        c=0
    print(c)
    if(c>=k):  print('pay 1 Dallor')
    else: print('pay nothing')
```

coinflip2(10,2)

Comment: Replace `for i in range (len(ϵ)):` with `for i in range (len(ϵ)-1):`?

Comment: Also note you can build `ϵ` without a python loop, using numpy directly: `ϵ = (np.random.uniform(0, 1, n) > 0.5)`